# Can Reverse Engineering produce code in a different language than the one the program was originally created?

Tags: disassemblers, decompile

Does Reverse Engineering always produces the source code in the same language the software was originally written?
For example, if the software program(.exe) been reversed was written in C++, the output of the reverse process would necessarily be C++ source code?

Comment: i think C would be the most convenable and lowest human-readable level language that a debugger can convert whatever language a code is written with, I think , in more brief terms, any language can be converted to C besides the original soure-compiled language (concrete example: hexrays), but C could not probably be converted to higher levels like python, pascal etc

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering is the process of figuring out how stuff works. The output format of a reverse engineering session is not dependent on the original language in which the target was written, but rather is dependent on the purpose of the session (porting to a new system, stealing a competitor's algorithm, explaining to executives how a malware sample works at a high-level, etc.).

The final product of a reverse engineering session may be a human-readable report, or pseudo-code, or a data-flow diagram, or a slide show presentation, or a reimplementation of the target in any language the reverse engineer wishes to use.

Comment: It may also be source code. For instance,**.exe** files consisting of MSIL code can be converted back into various .NET source languages.